# How to add input value, to a content, wrapped between div tags - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a input of type text and a button. After I enter a value inside the input and hit the button the content prints inside a div. The HTML code looks like this

```
    <div id="content">
        <input type="text" value="" class="input-value" />
        <button type="button" id="push" onclick="appendInput()";>push me</button>
        <div id="todo"></div>
    </div>
```

and the function to append the value of the input to a certain div looks like this

```
        function appendInput() {
            $('#todo').append($('.input-value').val());
        }
```

The content from the input is sent, but it just keeps on adding after the existing value. If I type **lorem** and hit the button and then i type again **ipsum** and hit the button once more the result is

```
    <div id="todo">loremipsum</div>
```

which brings me to the issue that I cannot manage. When the button is clicked the value adds inside the #todo div continuously. How can I send each sent value from the input wrapped between div tags? in order to have the result like this

```
    <div id="todo">
        <div>lorem</div>
        <div>ipsum</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to this...

```
function appendInput() {
    $('#todo').append('<div>' + $('.input-value').val() + '</div>');
}
```

That will automatically add each value wrapped in a div.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks.